# text wrap in subclassed QLabel when using stylesheets does not work

Tags: qt

I have subclassed QLabel as follows:

```
class TestLabel: public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestLabel(QWidget *parent = 0):QLabel(parent){}
    TestLabel(const QString& text, QWidget *parent = 0):QLabel(text, parent){}

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *paint)
     {
         QStyleOption opt;
         opt.init(this);
         QPainter p(this);
         style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
         style()->drawItemText(&p,this->rect(),Qt::AlignLeft, (this->palette()), true, this->text());

     }
};
```

I have setup the stylesheet as follows:

```
TestLabel {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}
```

I am trying to wrap text by using: `tlab->setWordWrap(true);`
Before overriding paintEvent, the text was being wrapped properly. But now, the text is no longer wrapped. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstylepainter.html#drawItemText) says that the **"The text is aligned and wrapped according to flags."**, but how do I pass in both flags(both of them are distinct enums)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I got the answer. I was looking at the wrong class. I was looking at QTextOption::WordWrap.

I needed to use **Qt::TextWordWrap** as `Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextWordWrap`